# Start a background process, write to stdin and read from stdout without blocking

Tags: bash, process, pipe

I have a program which reads from stdin and writes to stdout. In my example it is `cat`. I want to have three scripts to do something like the following:

1. `start.sh cat` would create a background process and any machinery required by the other two scripts.
2. `write.sh <pid> "hello"` would write `hello` to stdin of the previously created process, without closing it.
3. `read.sh <pid>` would read the stdout of this process, only the part written since the last read, in this case the `hello`, then print it and quit witout waiting for any more output.

I understand I can have (2) if I create a fifo file. And I can have (3) by directing the output to a file and rotating it. Is this a normal solution? It feels a bit ad hoc. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Using named pipes is a "normal" solution, at least as normal as it can be for such an *ab*normal question. What is it you're trying to do, and why are you doing it this way? (3) can also be done by second named pipe.

Comment: @muru how do I do (3) with a fifo? `cat output_pipe` does wait for more output. Do I just kill it? Somehow that seems to close my background script as well.

Comment: Try using `tail`, for example.

Comment: @muru I still don't see it. I first do `cat < iii > ooo`, then `cat > iii &` so it doesn't close, then `tail ooo`? That just eats up all the input.

Comment: If you're using `cat`, what do you expect to see?

Comment: @muru, I expect that when I do `echo hello > iii`, the output of the cat will be saved somewhere and then, when I do `tail ooo` or something else, this output will be printed, `tail` will close and the `cat` will remain open for another echo.

Comment: Then use a loop to read from `iii` and print to `ooo`.

Comment: @muru `cat` is an example. It will be something bigger and more stateful. Like `sh` or `mysql`, I'm not sure. I don't ever want to restart this background program.

Comment: I did ask you to explain what you are doing and why you are doing it this way. If you don't, that's the answer you get.

Comment: Are you going to communicate with the backgrounded `cat` or whatever via it's `STDIN` and `STDOUT`? Unless you can explain more clearly what you want to do, all I can suggest is a redesign.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain your requirements in more detail. As it stands, I don't see why you don't simply have input and output files doing all the work. You need to explain using a more representative example than `cat` and show us the behavior you need.

Comment: @terdon I'm having a hard time seeing what details are lacking. I think it's implicit that if `start.sh` starts the process, the other two scripts shouldn't be restarting it, or even care what that process is, aside from pid or some file names. And that the read/write scripts should be short lived and repeatable. Generally, I'm looking for a more flexible mode of communication than regular piping. I don't necessarily have a use case for this, but if it's possible, I'm sure I'd find plenty.